# Freebase API : User Rate Limit Exceeded

Tags: freebase

Had an issue with my application and I exceeded the per second user rate. This is the error I'm getting.

```json
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "userRateLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "User Rate Limit Exceeded. Please sign up",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "User Rate Limit Exceeded. Please sign up"
 }
}
```

I have fixed my code so I no longer will exceed the limit, but still getting the error even after 4 days. I really don't need more than the normal quota so how do I get past this?

Also what do they mean by Please sign up? Are they talking about requesting additional quota limits?

Is there a way to query Freebase to keep track of your query count on a per second basis and a 24 hour cycle? I am passing in my API Key.

Comment: Can you show me how you're passing your key in? (without posting the actual key). How have you verified that it is getting passed to the API?

Comment: Sure. Here is an example:                      https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query={"name": null, "type": "/type/type", "limit": 1, "instance": {"mid": null, "name": null, "limit": 1, "type": [], "id": "/en/blade_runner"}}&key =MyKey             Is this correct?

Comment: Are there spaces in the URL you request in your code? Spaces aren't allowed in URLs but many browsers automatically escape them and hide that from you.

Comment: Yes there are spaces in the MQL Query. I will take them out and give it another try.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Shawn, The issue was a space between key and the = sign. Spaces are ok in the MQL query itself, but not the rest of the URL.

Comment: You can accept your own answer if this is what solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

For the 2nd part of your question. If you go to the [API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) and click on Reports you'll see a graph of how many requests are being made to each API on a daily basis.

Comment: So becausehe had  a problem with spacing it gave you a USERLIMIT EXCEPTION. is that right? Man That's not right. it has nothing to do with spacing