# Freebase Error Code: 403 - User Rate Limit Exceeded. Please sign up

Tags: php, curl, localhost, freebase

I keep on getting the below error when fired from the code even though I have signed up and attach key to the url :-

```
Freebase Error Code: 403 - User Rate Limit Exceeded. Please sign up
```

When I try to fire the same url from the browser then the result set is displayed which shouldnt be the case as the error says I have crossed some limit or something.

My Query :-

```
    [{
  "id": null,
  "mid": "/m/07kw5b",
  "name": null,
  "/sports/sports_league/teams": [{
    "mid": null,
    "team": null,
    "/sports/sports_league_participation/team": [{
      "mid": null,
      "id": null,
      "name": null
    }]
  }]
}]
```

Below is the url:-

https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query=%5B%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09++%22id%22%3A+null%2C%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09++%22mid%22%3A+%22%2Fm%2F07kw5b%22%2C%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09++%22name%22%3A+null%2C%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09++%22%2Fsports%2Fsports_league%2Fteams%22%3A+%5B%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%22mid%22%3A+null%2C%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%22team%22%3A+null%2C%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%22%2Fsports%2Fsports_league_participation%2Fteam%22%3A+%5B%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09++%22mid%22%3A+null%2C%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09++%22id%22%3A+null%2C%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09++%22name%22%3A+null%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%7D%5D%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09++%7D%5D%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%7D%5D&key=[API-Key]&cursor

PHP Code:-

```
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  //the above url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
    $json_data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);

    curl_close($ch);
```

I have not fired the query more than 10 times and in my console too under freebase api it says "0 out of 100,000 requests".

My dashboard graph:-
[image]

Can anyone please give me some insights on why this error is coming?Is this something to do with configuration as I am firing the url from localhost.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Freebase API : User Rate Limit Exceeded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571991/freebase-api-user-rate-limit-exceeded)

Comment: I dont have any spaces in the url and I verified that too as per the solution of that thread, thats why I created a new thread.

Comment: Then you should always include what you've tried in your question, so that we know it's not a duplicate. Can you add the code you're using to make the request?

Comment: I have added the url now.

Comment: Using the code and url you provided, I can't reproduce the problem. I get a 200 response with a single result. Try using only that code in a single file, and see if it produces the error for you.

Comment: Thanks Jeremiah, For the update, But I am using my api key here and for that it gives me this message. Earlier it was working, its after 10-15 calls I made then it started to give me this error.

Comment: I have fixed the issue by replacing http_build_query() with urlencode()  to encode the json query and it started working for me.